# How do I parse uppercase strings in Nom?

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I'm writing parsers in Nom 5 using functions, not macros. My goal is to write a parser that recognizes a string composed entirely of uppercase characters. Ideally, it would have the same return signature as [alpha1](https://docs.rs/nom/5.0.0/nom/character/complete/fn.alpha1.html).

```
use nom::{
    character::complete::{alpha1, char, line_ending, not_line_ending},
    combinator::{cut, map, not, recognize},
    error::{context, ParseError, VerboseError},
    multi::{many0, many1},
    IResult,
};

fn uppercase_char<'a, E: ParseError<&'a str>>(i: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &'a str, E> {
    let chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    take_while(move |c| chars.contains(c))(i)
}

// Matches 1 or more consecutive uppercase characters
fn upper1<'a, E: ParseError<&'a str>>(i: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &'a str, E> {
    recognize(many1(uppercase_char))(i)
}
```

Although this compiles, the simple unit test I wrote fails:

```
#[test]
fn test_upper_string_ok() {
    let input_text = "ADAM";
    let output = upper1::<VerboseError<&str>>(input_text);
    dbg!(&output);
    let expected = Ok(("ADAM", ""));
    assert_eq!(output, expected);
}
```

The failure output is

```
---- parse::tests::test_upper_string_ok stdout ----
[src/parse.rs:110] &output = Err(
    Error(
        VerboseError {
            errors: [
                (
                    "",
                    Nom(
                        Many1,
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        },
    ),
)
thread 'parse::tests::test_upper_string_ok' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Err(Error(VerboseError { errors: [("", Nom(Many1))] }))`,
 right: `Ok(("ADAM", ""))`', src/parse.rs:112:9
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

Comment: Why `many1(uppercase_char)` and not just `uppercase_char`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`take_while` will recognize 0 or more characters, so when used inside of `many1` as you did, it will first parse the entire `"ADAM"` string. Then when `many1` calls it again, since `take_while` can recognize an empty string, it will succeed, but `many0` and `many1` have a protection against that mistake: if the underlying parser did not consume any input, they will return an error.

For what you need, the `uppercase_char` function should be enough, no need for `recognize` and `many1`. Although you might want to replace `take_while` with `take_while1`